# I am not able to use train_test_split .This module is not working

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-a118593bfefd>", line 7, in <module>
    from model_selection import train_test_split

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model_selection'
```

Comment: from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

Answer (score 0):

When you try to ask something on StackOverflow, you should provide your relevant code, not the error message only. It would help people reproduce your problem.
About your problem, it seems that you've written this

```
from model_selection import train_test_split
```

model_selection is a sub-module of sklearn. So you have to call it via sklearn like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```